# c++ application using qt, how to include gnuplot

Tags: c++, qt, gnuplot

Im looking for a solution or some guidelines on how to, from a c++ application using Qt, create scientific plots. I have set my mind on gnuplot because it have nice features for later use of my plots in latex and such.

My question is then, can i and how do i accomplish to show a plot in qt and also makes it possible to expose the gnuplot commands for generating the plot later for reporting.

Should i based on my data create some datafile, and create a text file with the commands?

Can it be integrated into my c++ application such that i create the plot, see it in my application and then save the data and plot file.

Any input would be nice. I dont now gnuplot at the moment, and wonder if its a application on unix or its a library i can use in my application. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to try Qwt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way is to have your app run gnuplot in a system() or similar call, plotting to an image and then display the image.

If you want more detailed control there is an [iostream lib](http://www.stahlke.org/dan/gnuplot-iostream/) to talk to gnuplot or an old [C interface](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/)

Comment: How does this work out for cross system solutions. I just make different methods for each system and call the right system call? Does the iostream lib work for cross system. Thanks.

Comment: All you would need to do is change the name/path of the gnuplot executable in the system call

Answer (score 0):

If your not set on gnuplot look into:

- KD Chart, it uses Qt ModelView programming model. It's cross platform and even has a plugin that appears as a widget in Qt Designer.
- The R-Project is great for plotting might be all you need as a standalone program, but also as a Qt interface R-Forge. It too is cross platform.

Note: 
I havn't tried R-Forge yet. R is actually a statistical programming language.
KD Chart targets business type charts but may have what you need.

Comment: Thanks. Had a hard time to find some examples of KD Chart, but I think that gnuplot offers a bit more scientific kind of plots, atleast for my taste in my reports. Thank you for the reply.